# Gaming Computer crashes to solid-colored screen when Steam application is installed

Tags: crash, amd-radeon, gaming, steam, intel-core-i5

```
Specs: Bazooka motherboard, Gigabyte AMD rx480 GPU, Intel Core i5-6600K 3.5 GHz

Processor Main Features: 64 bit Quad-Core Processor
Cache Per Processor: 6 MB L3 Cache
Memory: 8 GB DDR4
Storage: 2 TB SATA III 7200 RPM + 120 GB SSD
Optical Drive: 24x DVD±R/±RW Dual Layer Drive
Graphics: AMD Radeon RX 480 8 GB GDDR5
Power Supply: Thermaltake 650W 80+ 
Running Windows 10 Home 64-Bit
```

So, I've been having some complications with a gaming PC that I purchased from CyberPowerPC.  It seems that if Steam is simply installed (we're talking just presence on the hard drive here, so probably some background Steamish daemon? do those exist?) any normal computer operation will eventually lead to a crash with a random solid colored screen, with sound artifacts---only solution is a hard reset. Without steam installed, FurMark runs just fine, PCSX2 (PS2 emu) runs just fine, Mirror's Edge runs just fine, haven't tried a more recent title, but these have all crashed in the past when steam was a present entity in the system.  WHAT IS GOING ON?!  This is certainly one of the strangest PC problems I have ever seen.  Don't want to be relegated to playing non-steam-store games.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but might be helpful: I had same issue with an older AMD card and Youtube, whenever I had Youtube playing in background more graphically intensive games would crash the whole PC with random colored screen, only hard reset would bring the PC back. What I did was I disabled hardware acceleration in Youtubes Flash player and crashes stopped. However now Youtube uses HTML5 based video player and for still unknown reason PC is crashing again.

I am sure that VGA is to blame (at least in my case) because I switched it with another PC and old PC woks fine, only one with faulty video card crashes, so I would suggest borrowing a VGA from (or to) a friend to test it, or try on-board video, and if VGA is faulty just request a replacement.

One more notice, in my case crashes occur only in Windows, in Linux everything works just fine, so it might be related to VGA drivers.

Comment: That is interesting, I am using one HDMI-connected display (2560 x 1080) and one DVI (1280 x 1080).  I don't do much with the DVI, just offers extra space, as if my huge 27" wasn't enough already.. Alternatively this is a brand newish model AMD card for 2016 if I understand it correctly.  What is it about hardware acceleration that was causing youtube to crash? So you're saying that because of the switch to HTML5, you're experiencing crashes with your old AMD card?  Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

---

I think I have resolved my issue by reinstalling windows on the 2 terabyte disk-based harddrive, as opposed to the SSD.  I will be returning this SSD to CyberpowerPC. Steam games run just fine again, UHQ settings, 2560x1080. Shibbbyy